# jQuery Pajinate go to top of page on click

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination

I am using [jQuery Pajinate](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4151695/html/pajinate/examples/example1.html) plugin as a pager for news articles.  From a design and usability perspective I feel it is best to only have the pager at the bottom of the page. However when I do this it doesn't take me to the top of the page so the user may not be easily able to see that anything has happened here.  I can't see anywhere in the documentation where you can go to the top of the content on click. Has anyone come across this problem? I have trouble implementing something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/BctQL/) because the href generated by the pajinate plugin is empty eg href=""

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use unobtrusive jQuery to achieve the effect in your Fiddle.

```
$('a.class_for_pajinate').on('click', function() {
  top(); // Keep your functions starting with lower case
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BctQL/1/

Comment: Thanks that has worked for me. For those interested [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/BctQL/3/) is an example with the pager plugin.